# Assigning floor date in groupby fails

Tags: r, dplyr

this is my code and I have a problem with groupby :

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(lubridate)

    df <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Sector-STOXX600", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
    df[2:19] <- data.matrix(df[2:19])


 percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1

    monthly_return <- df %>% 
      group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
      summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(-gr) %>% 
      as.matrix()
```

Indeed I have this error :

> "Error in is_character(x) : object 'gr' not found"

Here is a sample of the dataset :

```
    Date  .SXQR  .SXTR  .SXNR  .SXMR  .SXAR  .SX3R  .SX6R  .SXFR  .SXOR  .SXDR  .SX4R  .SXRR  .SXER
1 2000-01-03 364.94 223.93 489.04 586.38 306.56 246.81 385.36 403.82 283.78 455.39 427.43 498.08 457.57
2 2000-01-04 345.04 218.90 474.05 566.15 301.13 239.24 374.64 390.41 275.93 434.92 414.10 476.17 435.72
```

## UPDATE

```
volatility_function<- function(x)sqrt(252) * sd(diff(log(x))) * 100
annualized_volatility <- df %>%
  mutate(Date=ymd(Date)) %>%
  group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "year")) %>%
  select(gr,everything()) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), volatility_function) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-gr) %>%
  as.matrix() 
head(annualized_volatility,5)
```

I tried what @NeslonGon told me to do, however I know get the same error on an another function, what should I do ?

Comment: Avoid using `$` when using `dplyr` and the pipe.

Comment: You could use mutate() instead of group_by() to create the new variable "gr". Then you could pipe that to group_by(). So it will be:
monthly_return <- df %>% mutate(gr = floordate(Date, unit = "month")) %>% group_by(gr) ...

Comment: @NelsonGon I tried but it gives the same error ..

Comment: Well, it  returns a different error for me: `Error in `[[.default`(object, name, exact = TRUE) : 
  subscript out of bounds` Could you add a `dput` of your data?

Comment: @NelsonGon Here is [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EmmqQAF1-UmpJC7qa_fV8iuSuLtbLqpj/view?usp=sharing) it's the df dataframe

Comment: @MadsObi thanks for your reply, however it gives the exact same error

Comment: I see now. Fortunately NelsonGon has provided at correct answer with an explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that we don't need to `summarise_at` a grouped variable but use the `Date` to account for this. The `select` and `mutate` calls can be skipped. They're for convenience.

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date=ymd(Date)) %>% 
 group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>% 
  select(gr,everything()) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(-Date), percent_change2) %>%  
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-gr) %>% 
  as.matrix()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works, however now I get the same error with an another function (see update)